# Set up ECLIPSE IDE Path

Tags: java, eclipse, runtime

I'm still working on this problem:
[Java Runtime command line Process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610469/java-runtime-command-line-process)

Based on what one of the contributors has said I tried the following:
So I've tried adding the path to "gs" in my "Run Configurations" -> Environment Tab and "Linked Resources" (Preferences -> General -> Workspace -> Linked Resources). Neither has worked...

But it's still not working, I'm getting the same error.

Any other ideas? Because I'm all out.

Comment: Didn't Erik B's answer work in your first question (Unix/Linux related)? Which OS do you use?

Comment: Hey, I really appreciate all your help. But I think you fail to understand, it's not a problem with the code. When I compile and run my java code from command line, it works! But in eclipse I get the aforementioned error. What's the problem with eclipse? What setting am I missing in eclipse???

Answer (score 3):

You can predefine the workspace via the startup parameter:

```
-data path_to_workspace,
```

e.g.

```
"c:\eclipse.exe -data "c:\temp"
```

Please note that you have to put the path name into brackets. To see the current workspace directory in the title of Eclipse use `-showLocation` as additional parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Java really knows nothing about your Windows PATH. You've got two options here:

1. Have your executable on your class path.
2. Have full path to your executable in your command line.

IMO #2 is much simpler. If you don't want to hard code it - read it from config file or supply it as system property.